# Llama v2 VRAM Usage Jumps during Inference

Tags: python, python-3.x, large-language-model, llama

I'm using an A10G 24GB for loading Llama-2-7b-chat-hf in `nf4`. This is how I load the model:

```
import torch
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, BitsAndBytesConfig, AutoTokenizer
from os.path import join

model_path = "path_to_the_model"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(join(model_path, "Llama2-7b-tokenizer"))
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token

bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
    load_in_4bit=True,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.float16,
)

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    join(model_path, "Llama2-7b-model"),
    quantization_config=bnb_config
)
model.config.use_cache = False
```

When I load model onto GPU, the VRAM usage is 4985MiB / 22731MiB, But after passing a simple prompt using the following code, the VRAM usage jumps to 20311MiB / 22731MiB.

```
from transformers import GenerationConfig

def generate_prompt(instruction, input=None):
    return f"""<s>[INST] <<SYS>>
Below is an instruction that describes a task. Write a response that appropriately completes the request.
{input}
<</SYS>>
{instruction} [/INST]"""

# Generate responses
def generate(instruction, input=None):
    prompt = generate_prompt(instruction, input)
    inputs = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt")
    input_ids = inputs["input_ids"].cuda()
    generation_output = model.generate(
        input_ids=input_ids,
        generation_config=GenerationConfig(temperature=0.2, top_p=0.75, num_beams=4),
        return_dict_in_generate=True,
        output_scores=True,
        max_new_tokens=512
    )
    # for seq in generation_output.sequences:
    output = tokenizer.decode(generation_output.sequences[0])
    return output
```

Do you have any idea what is going on with the GPU? Is there a way to do the inference more efficiently?

Thank you!

Comment: Any update on this?